# What's the simplest way to map an image to a square (2 triangle strip) in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I cannot seem to find a simple tutorial to address what I suspect is an overly easy problem:
I have a square built from a triangle strip.  I want to map an image to it (game sprite).  Everything is 2d, and lighting is not being used.

I have found tutorials addressing 3d objects with lighting, but they are addressing vastly more complicated scenarios.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GLES 2.0, the [`fixed-function pipeline`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) has been replaced with programmable [`shaders`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader). This means that you no longer can simply "enable" textures on your objects, but have to create the implementation yourself. Generally you will need to have a `texture-coordinate` attribute for the 2d-texture space of your geometry as well as a texture sampler.

Here is a simple example of a vertex and fragment shader using textures:

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
attribute vec2 texCoords;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
varying vec2 uv;
void main(){
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix*vertexPosition;
    uv = texCoords;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 uv;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, uv);
}
```

Then, before drawing you will have to [bind the texture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#glBindTexture%28int,%20int%29). If you only use one texture each drawing call then it is as simple as that.

For more code examples on loading and using textures, take a look at the GLES20 sample project in the Android [Api-demos](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)

Comment: Alright, so if I understand correctly I pass a second set of coordinates (U,V) which are the corners of the portion of the image to be mapped, in the order I want them to match the vertices from my vbo?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The coordinates should also be in the range 0-1, with the origin in the lower left corner (although, the gl-helpers in android might flip the image, I can't remember if it does).

Comment: Whoops, thought I was tracking with you... range 0-1?  So is it essentially a percentage of the image?

Comment: Great :) You can read a bit more on texture-mapping on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping